# Braintree Getting Started with Gradle in Android Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an existing `Android Project` that I created using the `Eclipse ADT`. I need to incorporate `Braintree` transaction capability into my application. Braintree's [Getting Started](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+java/start/hello-client) link, it mentions adding instructions to your `build.gradle` Can someone please provide step-by-step instructions on how to use `Gradle` with an existing `Android Project` in `Android Eclipse ADT`

Comment: Quoting the very page that you linked to: "Using Maven or Eclipse? [Check out the complete SDK docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/sdk/client)". That, in turn, links to [more detailed setup instructions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/android+java/sdk/client/setup). What part of those instructions did you have problems with?

Comment: @CommonsWare Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to use Maven either. Also, I followed this link and tried just downloading the source code for manual import of the project, but the repository is password protected for some reason.

Comment: Try this URL instead: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/braintreepayments/api/braintree/1.2.6/braintree-1.2.6-project.zip

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. I got the src and will try working through the example tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to be followed :

1. Right click on your project, click on export.
2. Select android and then generate gradle build files.
3. Click on next.

Thats it , now the build.gradle file will be added to your project.

NOTE : Before doing this,  install and configure Gradle plugin for eclipse.
       To do so follow this link : https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle